# Filesize in for loop

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am trying to get the filesize of each file in a folder by using stat in a for loop. I know why the following is going wrong, but I don't have enough knowledge yet on how to fix this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in .* *; do
     size=$(stat --printf="%s")
     echo $size
done
```

However, as stat is missing the filename, I logically get the following error:

```
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
```

How do I make sure stat gets the filename of every file (*only files*) in the folder?

EDIT: Coming from a Powershell background, I would use the variable '$_'. Does the Unix shell offer a similar variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving any argument (filename) to `stat` leading to that error.

You are using variable `file` to store the each filename and loop over them but you are not giving the filenames as arguments to `stat`. In a nutshell you need to pass `$file` (the value of variable `file`) to `stat`.

Also you can do all you are doing in one line :

```
for file in .* *; do stat -c '%s-%n' "$file" ; done
```

If you insist on the `printf` formatted output you need an extra `\n` :

```
for file in .* *; do stat --printf='%s-%n\n' "$file" ; done
```

Here i have also added `%n` so that you can get which file's size is being shown.

**EDIT :**

If you want to run this only on files excluding directories you need use an additional check. Here i have used `test` (`[`) builtin to check if `file` is a regular file, if so i.e. `[ -f "$file" ]` returns exit code 0  then (`&&`) run `stat` on the file :

```
for file in .* *; do [ -f "$file" ] && stat -c '%s-%n' "$file" ; done
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Just one quick question, is there any way to limit this to files only (excluding directories)?

Comment: @ses check my edit..